# SQLite for windows phone 8 does not compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I've downloaded the Windows Phone 8 extension for Visual Studio 2012 of SQLite from [this link.](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

However, upon compiling, I get this error:

> The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not
>   supported by the referenced SDK "SQLite.WP80, Version=3.7.15.2".
>   Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your
>   project (in visual studio this can be done through the Configuration
>   Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86,
>   ARM". FacebookRandomizerWindowsPhone

Obviously, I've tried changing the Platform target in the project in Visual Studio 2012, the same way I did with a Windows 8 app I've developed, which worked.

However, in the Windows Phone 8 application, I can't change the Platform Target, only the platform on the top, which does not change the platform target:

[image: Visual Studio]

Has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go To

> Build => Configuration Manager

and change settings from there

First you have to set the Configuration settings through *Configuration Manager* because your Build setup uses the settings defined through *Configuration Manager*

[image]

Comment: That did that, thanks. What's the difference between there and the edit project screen?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I managed to solve it by,
On my visual studio,I clicked build on the menu bar then configuration manager then I changed the platform from Any CPU to x86 as shown below.

[image]